# display selectedItems in a label

Tags: vb.net

I need to display the selecteditems in a label
I am using VB 2005
I set the selection mode to multi-extended
It did work selecting only one item with the following code:
me.xresultslabel.text= me.xlisttextbox.text.selectedItem.tostring

But when I tried to display more than one item using the following code:
me.resultlabel.text= me.xlisttextbox.text.selectedItems,  I get the following string on the label:
system.windows.forms.listbox+selectedobjetcollections.

any help will be highly appreciate

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim collection = Me.xlisttextbox.Text.SelectedItems
    Dim builder As New StringBuilder()

    For i As Integer = 0 To collection.Count - 1
        If i > 0 Then builder.Append(", ")
        builder.Append(collection(i))
    Next

    Me.resultlabel.Text = builder.ToString
```